# Java Transformation error (Message Code: JAVA PLUGIN_1762)

Tags: informatica

I have 2 csv source files.
I am using union transformation to consolidate the sources and then using Java transformation to generate rows for below sample rows :

```
COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN3 COLUMN4    
abc     VK123   DKVGH   VP234,VP111  
bbb     VK345   DGHKD   VP999,VM33
```

Target should be :

```
COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN3 COLUMN4  
abc     VK123   DKVGH   VP234  
abc     VK123   DKVGH   VP111  
bbb     VK345   DGHKD   VP999  
bbb     VK345   DGHKD   VM33
```

Code in JAVA transformation:

```
String str=COLUMN4;  
String[] temp;  
String delimiter = ",";  
temp = str.split(delimiter);  
for (int i =0; i< temp.length; i++){  
COLUMN4= temp[i];  
generateRow();  
}
```

Encountering the below errors after running workflow :

> Message Code: JAVA PLUGIN_1762
>   Message: [ERROR] java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> Message Code: JAVA PLUGIN_1762
>   Message: [ERROR]    at com.informatica.powercenter.server.jtx.JTXPartitionDriverImplGen.execute(JTXPartitionDriverImplGen.java:195)

Please provide me some inputs in order to fix these issues

Comment: Is your source file space/tab seperated?

Comment: @ Samik ..The source is comma separated

Comment: But Column4 contains a comma as well. Is it coming inside quotes?

Comment: @ Samik.. The sources are actually excel files, I am converting them to csv files. You are right, column4 has commas in it

Comment: ok, then it should be fine. Excel puts the value in quotes if there is comma inside. Make sure you specify double quotes in your source definition.

Answer (score 1):

Your Java code looks fine. Check if the value of column4 is coming as null. Alternatively, you can include null checking in the Java code.

```
if (COLUMN4 != null)
  str=COLUMN4;
else
  str="";
```

Comment: Thank you Samik !! that fixed the issues